# Minimalist, Tiny Javascript Template System?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I'm looking for a minimalist template system for javascript, ala [John Resig's Javascript Micro Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/). The smaller the better, and if it's jquery based even better. Recommendations?

I tried John's micro-templating but ran into a few issues, wanted to see if there are more baked / better packaged solutions out there.

[Update] I tried Resig's Micro Templating again and it's working well for me. Would still like to hear about other alternatives if there are any.

Comment: What kind of issue? I have used it and it works great!

Comment: What kind of problems were you running in to? That one seems pretty clever and basic. What more do you need from it?

Comment: The issue was likely me setting it up / using it incorrectly (I was attempting to integrate it into a larger project). I'm about to try it stand-alone and if that goes well I'll try the integration again.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In the end I went with John Resig's Micro Template, it's working nicely for me.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [Mustache.js](http://github.com/janl/mustache.js), it has a neat syntax IMO.

Answer (score 3):

This one is good and tiny (400bytes gzipped or 600bytes minified). Also has the attractive `{{hello}}` syntax rather than the **`<?php hideous ?>` <%whats-the-point-might-as-well-not-bother-with-templates%>** syntax

https://github.com/jasonmoo/t.js

Slightly larger but still very good (personally only tested mustache):

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

http://tempojs.com/

https://github.com/premasagar/tim (370 bytes for the 'tinytim' version)

Answer (score 1):

Theres [JBST](http://jsonml.org/bst/example/)

```
<a class="ExtLink"
            href="<%= "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + this.data.wiki %>"
            onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;"><%= this.data.name %></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

JBST (JsonML+Browser-Side Templating) is a good alternative to John Resig's Micro Template. It has a similar syntax but template parsing is not performed at runtime so it can be more compact and robust. The result of parsing is pure JavaScript which can be combined with other scripts and executed directly in the browser.

- the runtime format: http://jsonml.org/bst
- an example compiler: http://jbst.net
- syntax examples: http://starterkit.jsonfx.net/jbst
- a .NET implementation: http://jsonfx.googlecode.com

**UPDATE:** this system was rewritten from the ground up as a duel-side template library (client & server) called DUEL: http://duelengine.org

Answer (score 0):

I really like [**JST (JavaScript Templates)**](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates).  They use the same convention for tokens as JSPs ${} - pretty easy.